# Django - reduce the number of queries in ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I used related_name in a Django template to look the foreign key record, and call the count method. Because I have so many "Main" record, the for loop inside the template will create too many queries to the database. If there an easy way for me to reduce the number of queries to the database? Please see below for my setup.

```
# models.py  
class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)  

class Sub1(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255) 

class Sub2(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255) 

class Sub3(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)     

# views.py
def get_main(request): 
    main_list = Main.objects.all()
    ...

# template 
{% for main in main_list %}    
        {{main.sub1_set.count}}
        {{main.sub2_set.count}}
        {{main.sub3_set.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can annotate fields with the count value. There is an example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Answer (score 2):

You can use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-querysethttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) to do this logic all in one query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def get_main(request): 
    main_list = Main.objects.all().annotate(sub1_count=Count('sub1', distinct=True),
                                            sub2_count=Count('sub2', distinct=True),
                                            sub3_count=Count('sub3', distinct=True))
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for main in main_list %}    
    {{ main.sub1_count }}
    {{ main.sub2_count }}
    {{ main.sub3_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

(Edit: added `distinct`)

Comment: This might give the same result for all fields. It that happens, add `distinct=True` to the `Count()` calls.

Comment: can I still acess {{main.name}} inside the forloop then? Also, can you show how to use "distinct=True" in the code. Thanks!